# Serialize std::shared_ptr<> into and out of binary stream

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, stream, shared-ptr

I have a custom, generalized serialization system written in C++ where I've handled intrinsics, `std::string` and structures containing those.  However, for a memory stream class containing a `std::vector<byte>`, I'd like to make it possible to store and retrieve a `std::shared_ptr<T>` inside of it (where `T` is any class that derives from `Abstract`).  Of course, I'd like a solution **without using Boost** as it would defeat my intent.

As stated on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr :

> Constructing a new shared_ptr using the raw underlying pointer owned by another shared_ptr leads to undefined behavior.

The only (hacky) solution I have come up so far is for the binary memory stream class having a small lookup table of `std::shared_ptr<Abstract>` referenced by the raw pointer itself, making it fairly trivial to read and write them out, and ownership/reference count would be reliable.  Then it becomes possible/useful to serialize the raw pointer.

However, ownership/reference count is not of concern as it's guaranteed for the use case.  If there is a solution that would only use the `std::vector<byte>`, I would consider it a more elegant approach as it could provide other use cases.

Comment: You are serializing objects, and the lifetime of the serialization is bounded by the lifetime of the object being serialized?  This seems like a strange thing to do; serialization in my experience is about moving objects between "memory domains".  Is this some kind of strange round trip, where you send the data outside of your process, and it comes back? In any case, can you modify `Abstract` in any way?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I manage `Abstract` class.  It's a special case of serializing in parameters as a stream to an arbitrary function and calling it with those parameters by unserializing them out of that stream.  This is the same system used by my networking system, except this is a special case where I'd like to allow any types including strong pointers on the local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Since your serialization/deserialization process happens in the same process (i.e. the same memory space) then you can store the raw memory pointers as the binary data in your stream. Consider the idea below, written as a trivial demo.

Unfortunately, `std::enable_shared_from_this` does not allow to increment/decrement manually the reference counter because it is just storing a weak reference, that is not able to destroy the object on `ref == 0` internally. That is why we have to make a manual reference management, specifically for the instances in the byte stream.

```
class Abstract : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Abstract> {
public:
  Abstract() : _count(0) {}

  ~Abstract() { cout << "I am destoryed" << endl; }

  void incrementStreamRef() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    if (!_count) {
      _guard = this->shared_from_this();
    }
    ++_count;
  };

  void decrementStreamRef() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    if (_count == 0)
      return;

    if (_count == 1) {
      if (_guard.use_count() == 1) {
        // After this call `this` will be destroyed
        _guard.reset();
        return;
      }
      _guard.reset();
    }
    --_count;
  };

private:
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::shared_ptr<Abstract> _guard;
  std::size_t _count;
};

void addAbstractToStream(std::vector<uint8_t>& byteStream, Abstract* abstract) {
  abstract->incrementStreamRef();
  auto offset = byteStream.size();
  try {
    // 1 byte for type identification
    byteStream.resize(offset + sizeof(abstract) + 1);
    byteStream[offset]
      = 0xEE; // Means the next bytes are the raw pointer to an Abstract instance
    ++offset;
    // Add the raw pointer to the stream
    // prealocate memory here
    // byteStream.push_back(....;
    // ....
  } catch (...) {
    abstract->decrementStreamRef();
    return;
  }
  std::memcpy(byteStream.data() + static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(offset),
              (void*)&abstract,
              sizeof(abstract));
}

void removeAbstractFromStream(std::vector<uint8_t>& byteStream, std::size_t offset) {
  Abstract* abstract;

  std::memcpy((void*)&abstract,
              byteStream.data() + static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(offset),
              sizeof(abstract));

  abstract->decrementStreamRef();
}

void tryMe(std::vector<uint8_t>& byteStream) {
  // Must not be destoryed when we leave the scope
  auto abstract = std::make_shared<Abstract>();

  addAbstractToStream(byteStream, abstract.get());

  cout << "Scope is about to be left" << endl;
}

int main() {
  // Always walk over the stream and use `removeAbstractFromStream`
  std::vector<uint8_t> byteStream;

  // `try` to always clean the byte stream
  // Of course RAII is much better
  try {
    // Do some work with the stream
  } catch (...) {
    removeAbstractFromStream(byteStream, 1);
    throw;
  }

  tryMe(byteStream);

  cout << "Main is about to be left" << endl;
  removeAbstractFromStream(byteStream, 1);
  cout << "Main is even closer to be left" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, more elaborate locking could be fine, or discarded at all if the thread-safety is not a concern. Please, revise the code for corner cases before using in production.

Comment: You mentioned a lot of things that I already mentioned in my question.  But to clarify some things -  I am indeed inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this` and the original type isn't a concern since I can cast out of `Abstract` appropriately.

Comment: No, this isn't right. I said things inherit from `Abstract` - however, no class actually is of type `Abstract` and your `addAbstractToStream`/`removeAbstractFromStream` assume it's always the base class. I've gone ahead with my "hacky" solution since it handles ownership, until further notice.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<T> inside of it (where T is any class that derives from Abstract).` Did not this mean that you inherit all your class from `Abstract`?

Comment: Yes, but you can't simply `memcpy` the base class and expect the derived classes' details to be transferred as well.

Comment: I do not `memcpy` the class instance itself, I `memcpy` only the pointer, because you said that your serialization/deserialization process work in the same process (the same memory space).

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to decipher the actual answer in your large block of code.  Essentially at the end of the day, your suggestion is storing a strong pointer inside of the `Abstract` class so it's later retrievable, yes?  Seems reasonable; will ponder on it.

Comment: Yes it does, the first sentence of the post mentions it.

Comment: I wouldn't say the first sentence says that at all, but I understand you now.